# Send audio data in selected bitrate - SHOUTcast

Tags: c++, sockets, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I was able to connect to SHOUTcast server via sockets. I try to send audio data to server, but I haven't idea how to calculate quality (bitrate) in each of the packages. Could someone explain this to me?

1. I open the mp3 in binary mode.
2. loop ?

Answer (score 0):

The bit rate is set by the encoder. It doesn't have anything to do with your SHOUTcast connection really. Configure your encoder for whatever bit rate you need.

Comment: But how to send mp3 to the server via socket, just open and loop?

Comment: Just send the MP3 data, yes.